# netbeans - java modules

Tags: java, netbeans

I have recently been trying to run Java on Netbeans and here is what it gives me as an error.

Here is the option that I select
[image]

The error messages it gives me
[image]

For information, I have downloaded the JDK version 8.

Thanks in advance!